# MySQL Slave Error

Tags: mysql, master-slave

I am getting an error on the slave machine.

While I give Show Slave Status, it shows the following error

```
Error 'Table 'mysql.yongger2' doesn't exist' on query.
Default database: 'mysql'. Query: 'insert into yongger2 values("")'
```

This table was not created by any user or the application.

Can someone help me to identify the issue? I am running on MySQL 5.0.95 version on both master and slave.

On analyzing the binlog file, could find update statement, on the same table with different values and dropping the table at a later stage.

Is it some hackers activity?

Comment: you should refer this link:(http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-repair-mysql-replication)

Comment: Not sure on how this tables are created automatically... Could u please help me on that??